# Create a page in react that auto adds the input field, once the initial input fields are being writen

Tags: reactjs

I am learning React and I am trying to create a page that has an input field and as soon as the user clicks on the field to write something in it, another one should appear.
What I have done so far is:

```
import { useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
function AddPlayers(){

    const players=[]
    const [addMoreField,setAddMoreField] = useState(true);

    const dispatch = useDispatch();

    const addPlayers = ()=> {

        setAddMoreField(false);
        dispatch({type:'INITIAL', players: players});

    };

    function addNewRow(){
        setAddMoreField(true);
    }

    function addPlayerName(e){
        players.push(e.target.value);
        console.log(players);
    }


    return(
        
        <div>
            {(()=>{
                do{
                    console.log("Inside do");
                    setAddMoreField(false);
            <>
            <input type='text' onFocus={addNewRow} placeholder='Add Player Name'  onBlur={addPlayerName}></input>
            </>
            console.log("After do");
                }while(addMoreField)})
                ()}
            <button onClick={addPlayers}>DONE</button>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AddPlayers;
```

I have called a do-while loop for atleast one input field and then when that comes into focus `addMoreField` becomes true and the loop keeps on repeating itself, untill the `DONE` button is clicked which resets the flag `addMoreField`.

But when it renders the page, I do not see the initial text field at all. I am not sure what is wrong here. Can someone please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

Basically react re-render components when state is updated.
That's why do-while doesn't work.

This is not auto adds the input field, once the initial input fields are being written but it might help you.

I've added remove field feature as well.

```
import { useState } from "react";

const DynamicForm = () => {
  const [formValues, setFormValues] = useState([""]);

  const handleChange = (i, e) => {
    const newFormValues = [...formValues];
    newFormValues[i] = e.target.value;
    setFormValues(newFormValues);
  };

  const addForm = () => {
    setFormValues([...formValues, ""]);
  };

  const removeForm = (i) => {
    const newFormValues = [...formValues];
    newFormValues.splice(i, 1);
    setFormValues(newFormValues);
  };

  const handleSubmit = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(formValues);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      {formValues.map((playerName, index) => (
        <div className="form-inline" key={index}>
          <label>Name</label>
          <input
            type="text"
            name="name"
            value={playerName || ""}
            onChange={(e) => handleChange(index, e)}
          />
          {index !== 0 && (
            <button
              type="button"
              className="button remove"
              onClick={() => removeForm(index)}
            >
              Remove
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div className="button-wrapper">
        <button className="button add" type="button" onClick={() => addForm()}>
          Add
        </button>
        <button className="button submit" type="submit">
          Submit
        </button>
      </div>
    </form>
  );
};

export default DynamicForm;
```

codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/embed/fast-shape-egh8i

Also I suggest that you should know ECMAScript :)